# Module-scoped css files

Tags: angular

TLDR in Angular 9, is it possible to lazy load CSS styles (not component-specific)?

---

My module structure:

```
AppModule
  |--AppFormsModule
  |--AppSharedModule

AdminModule
  |--AppFormsModule
  |--AppSharedModule
```

AdminModule is lazy loaded via a route in my main app module:

```
{
  path: appPaths.admin.path,
  canLoad: [ChapterAdminGuardService],
  loadChildren: () => import('../modules/admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule)
}
```

I have some amount of css that is specific to several components in the admin module. It is currently bundled into the global css file along with the css used by my main module.

Is it possible to lazy-load this css from somewhere else? With the clear benefit that extra resources aren't downloaded by the client until needed.

Ideally I would be able to specify that specific style bundles should be loaded for specific modules.

I am also open to different approaches. For example - is it possible to specify that a module should use a different version of index.html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the root component of the `AdminModule`, let's call it AppComponent, and use the `::ng-deep` (deprecated) selector in combination with `:host`. Even though this selector is deprecated, they will not remove it until there is a suitable replacement option:

app.component.scss:

```
:host ::ng-deep {
  // This will make any paragraph element which is a child of the app-component element red 
  p {
    color: #F00;
  }
}
```

And by adding it as a component specific stylesheet, this will be lazy loaded when the admin module is loaded.

---

If you want to use ViewEncapsulation.None, you can do something like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-module',
  styleUrls: [ './admin.component.scss' ],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AdminComponent {}
```

admin.component.scss:

```
app-admin-module {
  // declare all your module styles here
  p {
    color: #F00;
  }
}
```

Comment: Reading up on this also led me to find `ViewEncapsulation.None`. If I add this to my root component, and add regular styles (without `::ng-deep`) to my root component css, they get bundled into the module js. I reckon that they are equivalent in what they achieve - would you say so?

Comment: Not really, because styles can bleed to parent and unrelated elements. The styles defined in the stylesheet will be global. To take my example with the paragraph element. Any paragraph element in your application will be red after you've visited the admin module

Comment: True. View encapsulation actually suits my use case because my lazy module only shares descendant components with other modules, not ancestors. Your answer is a pure general solution to my question as it was stated, albeit deprecated.

Comment: @KurtHamilton I've updated my answer with what I think is a working example with using ViewEncapsulation.None without style bleeding to any other elements but children