# Load CSS Module Wise in Angular

Tags: css, angular

Here is the scenario -

I have multiple modules in my angular application. Ex -

```
app.module.ts
    student.module.ts
        component A
        component B
        component C
    admin.module.ts
        component A
        component B
        component C
    .
    .
    .
```

As per the above hierarchy , I have two  new modules(student & admin) and each module has separate components.

Now I want to load CSS file module wise so that it can be apply on all components of that module , not outside that module.

If I call CSS file in style.css then it will be apply globally which I don't want.

So is there any way to do this because I don't want to write CSS in each component's css file because it is common for specific module's components.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of a question I asked recently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60126877/module-scoped-css-files

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Module-scoped css files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60126877/module-scoped-css-files)

Answer (score 0):

I don't now if it work but you try this:

Put this in your component:

```
 import 'path/folder/module.css';
```

Put the .css path in this import